# preview and rendered image of scene strip in VSE not updating upon frame change

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, error

I have a scene #1 with animated stuff and another #2 where I only have a strip in the Video Sequencer that is scene #1, adding a speed effect strip (to add some slowing down and freezing of the original scene #1).

When I increase or decrease the frame number, the preview of the output and the output itself don't change.  Only if I e.g. select and move one of the strips, even if I abort the moving.  This seems to suggest that this is not a feature but a bug. It worked prior to some changes in my work, I don't know what I changed that breaks it now.  Any idea?

Comment: Maybe, it has something to do with the cache. With the menu View > Refresh All (Ctrl - R), you can force the cache to be recreated. Does this help?

Comment: Ctrl-R in the video strip editor does update the preview, yes. But in rendering, the frame that is rendered does not advance. A 20-frame sequence results in 20 identical images.